# Rendering content from div to inside a hierarchical shadow dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a special requirement not sure its possible or not. Here is the context.

I have hierarchical shadow dom in body tag of my dom. Something like this.

```
<body>
<shadowDom>
    <shadowDom>
        <shadowDom>

        </shadowDom>
    </shadowDom>
</shadowDom>
<div id="outside"><p>Hello world</p></div>
</body>
```

The number of levels of shadow dom is dynamic. Basically each shadow is a web component. and Every component has its own shadowDom.

Now the question is I have a  some content  in body outside of all shadow dom.

I want to render this div in innermost shadow dom. Is there any way to achieve this in React or by basic JS.

I have seen one example using slots but seems its with one level of shadow dom only.

Answer (score 0):

In other words:

You have a package outside your front-door and you want it placed on the lower shelf of the right cabinet in your kitchen

That means

- either the lower shelf itself fetches the package at the front-door.
- or some code finds the lower shelf and puts the package there

(incomplete!!) psuedo code:

```
get body
found-shadowroot = false

do :loop children(body)

:loop children(element)
 if child has shadowroot
   then do :loop children(child)
   else found-shadowroot = child
 if found-shadowroot
   then put content in found-shadowroot
```

This should immediately raise the question:
shadow roots at same level all get content?

```
<shadowDom>
    <shadowDom> 
       content here?
    </shadowDom>
    <shadowDom>
       content here?
    </shadowDom>
</shadowDom>
```

You have a programming challenge,

- start with 2 levels
- `SLOTs` will complicate your code, as you then have to pass content through nested slots

Depending on your use-case you might want to use Events.

- If all shadowDoms *listen* at document level
- All shadowDOMs know who they are :  `id=leftShelfRightCabinet`

Then you can do:

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
  "ContentEvent", {
    detail: {
      content: CONTENT,
      for: "leftShelfRightCabinet"
    }
  }
))
```

Comment: Will this look like processing of all stuffs are actually present outside of shadow dom but actual point where we see it renders is inside shadow dom? Or in real it will move my outer div to inside of shadow dom. My requirement is earlier one.